# Google Apps Script: create sequential ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheet as a basic database. The one-to-many relationship in question here is a "Leads" sheet and a "Comms" sheet. Each lead can have a number of communications (emails, tweets, phone calls, etc.)

When a user fills in a Google Form, I have a script that inserts some of the data from the associated form sheet into the "Leads" sheet, and also emails the user:

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
 srcSheet.getRange(srcLastRow, 1).copyTo(leadsSheet.getRange(leadsLastRow + 1, 1));     // Copy timestamp
 srcSheet.getRange(srcLastRow, 6).copyTo(leadsSheet.getRange(leadsLastRow + 1, 5));     // Copy first name
 srcSheet.getRange(srcLastRow, 7).copyTo(leadsSheet.getRange(leadsLastRow + 1, 6));     // Copy surname
 leadsSheet.getRange(leadsLastRow + 1, 3).setValue("Web - Unknown");                    // Mark as WEB lead
 leadsSheet.getRange(leadsLastRow + 1, 4).setValue("New");                              // Set status to NEW
 // Email the user ...
}
```

I also want to generate an ID so I can tie comms back to a given lead. What's the best way to do this? Ideas I've thought of so far include generating a very long GUID, or using a sequential ID, e.g. L1, L2, L3, etc.

I prefer the latter idea for readability and to give a better insight into the data, but

a) what code would I use to find the last ID with the L prefix, and increment this?

b) what's the best way to prevent incrementing the ID incorrectly in the case where I re-sort the sheet?

Comment: If you create an ID based on the date and time, then there will never be duplicate ID's, and you don't need to search for the last ID.  This millisecond in time is not going to occur again.  If you have a situation where lots of users could be submitting data at the "same time", then you can use LockService (which you should use anyway) to make sure that a section of code does not end up being simultaneously run.

Answer (score 1):

Every response has a timestamp. You could use it as the response ID.

Another alternative is to use the response_id in the edit response URL.

A response URL looks like the following

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/0awKpg_finiay86360kNXrcjihl36azP3DJEaZqXDY7A/viewform?edit2=2_ABaOmuk-sIHc2HrfDJO6d8CsST-Te-5ib2l0uFknhPt0DyjM3YhSXEkEtyirN8l
```

the response_id is the string after `edit2=`, so for the above example, the response_id is

```
2_ABaOmuk-sIHc2HrfDJO6d8CsST-Te-5ib2l0uFknhPt0DyjM3YhSXEkEtyirN8l
```

To get the unique response URL use [FormResponse.getResponseUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response.html#getEditResponseUrl())

Comment: Definitely a good response. My fault, but I should have mentioned I want to standardise the method of creating IDs for different sheets that won't have forms attached, e.g. an Accounts sheet, a Task sheet, etc. So I would have L1, L2, L3 for leads and A1, A2, A3 for accounts. Any other ideas gratefully received!

Comment: Thanks. Regarding  the "missing requirement", consider to post a new question including all the important details.